# Exuberant Ctags: CTRL-] and ":tag" went wrong

Tags: ctags

When I hit `<C-]>` or type `:tag {indent}`, vim does not jump to the first tag that matches the keyword under the cursor. Instead, it prompts me to select from multiple matches for the word.

Vim mistakes `<C-]>` for `g<C-]>` and `:tag {indent}` for `tjump {indent}`.

---

**Update:**

1. When I launch vim without sourcing my `.vimrc` file, `<C-]>` or `:tag {indent}` is ok, whether all initializations are skipped with the argument `-u NONE`, or just the plugins are sourced with the argument `-u NORC`.
2. When I launch vim sourcing my `.vimrc` file, `<C-]>` or `:tag {indent}` goes wrong, whether I skip loading plugins with the argument `--noplugin` or not.

Comment: Maybe a file has remapped your `<C-]>` key. To find out which one, type: `:verbose nmap <C-]>`

Comment: @saginaw vim echo `No mapping found `

Comment: @saginaw Note that `:tag {keyword}` went wrong too. If I have remapped my `<C-]>` key, `:tag {keyword}` should work right at least.

Comment: @FengYu Yes you're right. Maybe there's a problem with the tags file and how it was created. You say it works when you start vim like this `vim -u NONE` but not when you start vim with an empty vimrc file and .vim/ folder. I may be wrong, but it seems to suggest a file is messing with the behavior of your mappings / commands. If you start vim like this : `vim -u NORC`, all initializations from files and environment variables are skipped except plugins. Is the issue still there when you start vim like this ?

Comment: @FengYu Just a suggestion, type `vim --startuptime log1`, quit then type `vim -u NORC --startuptime log2`, quit then type `vim -u NONE --startuptime log3`, quit then type `vim -d log1 log2 log3`. Maybe it will help you find a file which is messing with your commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see all the files that Vim sourced during launch, I typed `:scriptnames`.

I found that:

1. When launching vim with the command `$vim --noplugin` or `$vim`, there is a `/etc/vimrc` file which is sourced;
2. When launching vim with `$vim -u NONE` or `$vim -u NORC`, this `/etc/vimrc` file is gone.

There are other differences in the list of sourced files, but only `/etc/vimrc` caught my eye because `vimrc` is included in this path.

Then I experimented with `/etc/vimrc` and I found that one statement in it was modifying the behavior `<C-]>` and `:tag {indent}`:

```
set cscopetag
```

When I comment out this line, the problem no longer exists.

From the vim help (`:help cscopetag`):

> If 'cscopetag' is set, the commands ":tag" and CTRL-] as well as "vim
>   -t" will always use :cstag instead of the default :tag behavior.

`:help :cstag`:

> If you use cscope as well as ctags, |:cstag| allows you to search one
>   or the other before making a jump.  For example, you can choose to
>   first search your cscope database(s) for a match, and if one is not
>   found, then your tags file(s) will be searched.  The order in which
>   this happens is determined by the value of |csto|.  See
>   |cscope-options| for more details.
>
> |:cstag| performs the equivalent of ":cs find g" on the identifier
>   when searching through the cscope database(s).
>
> **|:cstag| performs the equivalent of |:tjump| on the identifier when
>   searching through your tags file(s).**